# NativeScript Google Maps SDK - Marker Randomly Jumping W/ Multiple MapViews

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-google-maps-sdk

This only happens on Android.  When you have both Map 1 and Map 2 open, go to either tab and click on a marker to show the "Favor Me" button. If you spam that button, the markers will jump randomly. When the markers are randomly moved, if you scroll the map, everything goes back to normal. If you hide one map and try to spam the favor button, this bug does not happen.

NativeScript: 5.3.2

tns-core-modules: 5.3.2

tns-android: 5.3.1

tns-ios: 5.3.1

nativescript-google-maps-sdk: ^2.7.0

Screenshot of the bug can be found here:
https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/issues/344

Map 1 and Map 2 both use the same component.  I tried splitting this into separate components but still no luck.

Source code:
https://github.com/18clans/google-maps-tab-view

When I favor a marker on Map 1, Map 2 marker with the same ID should be favorited as well. This is working fine on iOS.

I also found something similar to this bug on a different language.
[Jumping markers on Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131387/jumping-markers-on-google-maps)